# Trying to program a timer to do something when it reaches 5 seconds

Tags: unity-game-engine, stopwatch

I can't seem to figure out what to do here. I'm creating a learn to type game where if the user doesn't get the word correct in 5 seconds, they lose a life.

Either this could be implemented by counting down to 0 from 5, or counting up to 5.

I tried using the stopwatch for c# system diagnostics, which works for everything except I can't figure out how to check when it hits 5 seconds. It is a time object you cant compare it to an int.

Comment: note that when coding in unity for devices you must avoid .net framework classes as much as possible for saving the build size. (except for mscorlib)

Answer (score 5):

you have two options here.

You can check the time in the Update function with Time.time or Time.deltaTime, or you can use a Coroutine with the new WaitForSeconds(5) object.

It could be as simple as:

```
float time;
void Update()
{
    time += Time.deltaTime;
    if(time > 5)
    {
        LoseALife();
    }
}
```

If you need to restart the timer each time you complete a word you might have an aditional method like:

```
public void RestartTimer()
{
    time = 0;
}
```

This would make the timer go back to 0 any moment you need it.

Comment: the only issue is that there are multiple words, so the timer would need to restart everytime after they complete a word

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my answer to make it work with multiple words